# Sistema de sesiones multiples simultaneas Java

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, javafx

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto personal en Java, una aplicacion de escritorio con JavaFx.

---

La aplicacion se apoya en una base de datos local con mysql, se aloja en una tabla users la informacion: username, securePassword, saltValue, isAdmin, isActive.

La idea de la aplicacion es que pueda soportar multiples sesiones activas simultaneamente, que dos pc puedan utilizarla al mismo tiempo en sesiones diferentes.

Para lograr esto implemente una clase UserSession que se encarga de mantener el estado de la sesion de un usuario, tambien implemente una clase SessionManager (con un patron de diseño singleton) que proporciona una forma de mantener un registro de todas las sesiones activas en un momento dado, haciendo uso de un mapa para asociar un nombre de usuario con una sesion especifica, la clase UserSession proporcionaria una abstraccion de una sesion individual con sus propiedades y metodos.

Clase UserSession:

```
public class UserSession {
private boolean isActive;
private String username;
private boolean isAdmin;
private DatabaseService db = new DatabaseService();

public UserSession(String username) {
    this.username = username;
    this.isActive = setIsActive(username, true);
    this.isAdmin = isAdmin();
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    try {
        isActive = db.isActive(this.username);
        return isActive;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean setIsActive(String username, Boolean isActiveSet) {
    try {
        if (db.setIsActive(username, isActiveSet)) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isAdmin() {
    try {
        return db.isAdmin(this.username);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public void setIsAdmin(boolean isAdmin) {
    try {
        return db.setIsAdmin(this.username, isAdmin);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Clase SessionManager:

```
public class SessionManager {
private static SessionManager instance;
private Map<String, UserSession> sessions;


private SessionManager() {
    sessions = new HashMap<>();
}

public static SessionManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new SessionManager();
    }
    return instance;
}

public UserSession getSession(String username) {
    return sessions.get(username);
}

public void addSession(String username, UserSession session) {
    sessions.put(username, session);
}

public void removeSession(String username) {
    sessions.remove(username);
}
```

}

El problema que estoy afrontando trata de como puedo identificar quien es la sesion que esta tomando determinada accion.

- Si mi "servidor" funciona como una base de datos local, deberia
  guardar los identificadores en un espacio de almacenamiento, con un
  tiempo de vida y luego se destruya? no es un riesgo de seguridad?
- Como envio el identificador a la consulta?

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si es una app de escritorio, ya tenes una sesion, y es la app abierta en el escritorio.. sera que estas pensando en web?

Comment: Disculpa si formule mal la pregunta.
La idea de mi proyecto es poder hacer una aplicación enlazada a una base de datos local, la cual, supongamos que hay dos programas corriendo, puedan funcionar con dos sesiones diferentes.
Es a lo que voy, siguiendo esa lógica, con utilizar UserSession como objeto de la sesión actual estaría hecho. Pero esto ¿no generaría un problema si mientras hay una sesión activa, se inicia otra sesion?

Comment: y en el cliente que tienes?

Comment: Pero.. es una app de escritorio!! no hay sesiones!!! a que llamas sesion??? no es una aplicacion web... creo que de ahi tu confusion...

Comment: Es probable que me este confundiendo, ya me quemó los pelos. La idea es que pueda funcionar por ejemplo, en una conexion LAN, habria una pc que hace de "servidor" y las demas de "cliente".

Comment: El identificador en una aplicación web, podría ser una variable de sesión; en una API REST, podría ser un identificador de sesión en el encabezado de la petición. Pero en un sistema cerrado? repito, puedo estar confundido, pero no veo el porque no se podria lograr.

Comment: Una sesión guarda la información de la sesión de un usuario. En la DB sé que sesion esta activa y cual no, con la clase SessionManager genero un mapa de todas las sesiones activas, se actualiza cuando se crea una nueva o se cierra. El problema es como identificarlas.